# SolrClient does not timeout even after passing the socket timeout parameter

Tags: java, solr

I have my SolrClient implementation written in java. I have been testing the load on my service and solr_6.6.0 and it seems it is not timing out even after mentioning the timeout parameter (as the log message with the total solr time is visible in splunk with total time being 158 secs). I believe this is causing 502 for other request coming in (I have couple of instances of service running) and the time taken by solr is increasing drastically. I have couple of replicated instances of solr running too.

CloudSolrClient 6.5.1:

```
public class SolrClientWrapper {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SolrClientWrapper.class);
private final CloudSolrClient solrClient;
private PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connMgr;


public SolrClientWrapper(List<String> solrZkHosts, Integer maxConnPerRoute,
                         Integer connectTimeoutInSeconds, Integer connectionRequestTimeoutInSeconds,
                         Integer socketTimeoutInSeconds, Integer httpClientMaxConn) {

    RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
                                               .setConnectTimeout(connectTimeoutInSeconds.intValue() * 1000)
                                               .setConnectionRequestTimeout(connectionRequestTimeoutInSeconds.intValue() * 1000)
                                               .setSocketTimeout(socketTimeoutInSeconds.intValue() * 1000)
                                               .build();

    connMgr = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
    connMgr.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(maxConnPerRoute.intValue());
    connMgr.setMaxTotal(httpClientMaxConn.intValue());

    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
                                                .setConnectionManager(connMgr)
                                                .build();

    solrClient = new CloudSolrClient.Builder()
            .withZkHost(solrZkHosts)
            .withHttpClient(httpClient)
            .build();
}


public QueryResponse query(SolrQuery query, String collection) throws SolrClientException {
    try {
        
        LOGGER.debug("Making a Solr request for collection={}, query={}: ", collection,query.toString());
        QueryResponse response = solrClient.query(collection, query, SolrRequest.METHOD.POST);
        LOGGER.info("Response for collection={} and query={} with status={}, timeToExecuteTheQuery={}, totalTimeTaken={}",
                collection,query,response.getStatus(),response.getQTime(), response.getElapsedTime());

        return response;
    } catch (Exception se) {
        LOGGER.error("Exception: Query to solr collection failed with exception. collection={} message={}",
                                   collection, se.getMessage(), se);
        LOGGER.info("atException connectionPoolStats={}",connMgr.getTotalStats());
        throw new SolrClientException(se.getMessage(), se);
    }
}
```

}

When I verifying in splunk on how much time solr is taking, it is approx 158 secs (probably because I have another service which indexes the documents in the same collection at the same time, I am not sure I need to figure that out separately). But I am expecting the client to timeout in this case so that it can server other request.

Configuration in my service:

```
  max-limit: 500
  http-client-connection-request-timeout-in-seconds: 20
  http-client-connect-timeout-in-seconds: 5
  http-client-socket-timeout-in-seconds: 20
  http-client-max-conn-per-route: 50
  http-client-max-conn: 600
```

Comment: `setSocketTimeout` adjusts the time to wait _between packets_, not the total time to keep the socket open. `connectionRequestTimeout` is "_timeout in milliseconds used when requesting a connection from the connection manager._". So neither of the options you set means "total time for request". I think you'd either have to find a way to change [the setConnectionTimeToLive value](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder.html) - or wrap it in a separate thread / alarm that you can time out..

Comment: "SocketTimeout adjust the time to wait between packets" : You mean if is not the time it waits for the reply from the server (solr) but waits on other request packets coming in to send it to the server (solr)

Comment: It's the time between any data arrives; so if it's a larger result set or any response from the server at all, that will reset the timing. Solr will stream it result sets as results become available under certain output formats. You should be able to server this with wireshark or tcpdump